# How do I output certain index values from a foreach array?

Tags: php, pdo

This is the structure in the database:

```
items    |itemLink
----------------------
Kill Bill|Kill Bill link
Preman   |Preman link
```

This is the code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

            $items = 'SELECT items FROM menus';
            $itemLink = 'SELECT itemLink FROM menus';

            $itemQuery = $db->query($items);
            $linkQuery = $db->query($itemLink);

            $fetchItem = $itemQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $fetchLink = $linkQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $merged = array_merge($fetchItem,$fetchLink);

            foreach($merged as $entry) {
            foreach( $entry as $key => $value ) {

          }
        }
```

From the above code, how do I output only the items' datas?

Comment: Why do you run two separate queries?

Comment: Just for experimental purposes...

Comment: I would replace `foreach( $entry as $key => $value ) {}` with `$entry['items']` otherwise you will need to do a `if($key=='items')` in that inner loop.

Comment: Do some var_dumps how the array or variable looks like, eg. $value['Items']['items']. The first one is the db the second one is the column.

Answer (score 1):

Using the example above you could then do something like this to answer you question

```
        $result = mysql_query('Select * from names');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
           echo $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["LastName"] . "<br>";
        }

        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this, not two arrays for something that could be one query. I have shown three methods, using var_dump or print_r will show how each works.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db('sample', $conn);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die("Can\t use db : '  . mysql_error()");
        }
        $result = mysql_query('Select * from names');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $result = mysql_query('Select * from names');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $result = mysql_query('Select * from names ');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
```